# Personal advices instead of general questions means low reusability

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, localized-questions

I note that this question implicitly prefers questions with a general topic but in fact very localized content (one's life story + a question of type 'What should I do?').

For example, one I asked a general question (i.e. if one can use his/her personal e-mail instead of institutional) then it was pointed out that in fact there were such question before (as a side part of a compound/story type question).

AFAIK it is not a good practice for a SE site.

First, it makes things less reusable.

- An answered question makes less sense to others.
- It is harder to find.

Second, it makes harder to make meaningful answers.

- If there are more subquestions and answer covering only some may be accepted.
- As a specific context is given, the answer may not be true in a more general one.

Comment: I'm not so sure what you want to discuss with this post, as I don't see an explicit discussion question. Are you asking whether that style of question is constructive and should be encouraged?

Comment: @eykanal It is a more a comment. And yes, the question asked implicitly is whenever other users agree with this point of view. If so then there is a separate issue what can be done (in terms of dis/encouraging, editing, closing, allowing, etc).

Answer (score 5):

Well, academics to tend to talk a lot :)

Seriously, though, there's a balance between providing useful context and writing a blog post. I can think of two approaches to this:

- We can make use of the beta to try to emphasize conciseness in the comments
- We can try to emphasize conciseness over extensive background in the FAQ (I'm thinking it would be most appropriate in the [etiquette section](https://academia.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette), but that can be discussed later).

Given our audience, though, this will probably be a problem we'll see often.

Answer (score 5):

Such questions should be closed as too localized. They're not of general use to the readership.